# Триггер для проверки того, не пересекают ли даты уже существующие

Tags: sql, oracle, триггер

Имеется таблица, которая записывает время начала и конца занятия (в спортивном клубе). Необходимо создать триггер для проверки того, что время занятий у разных групп в ОДНОМ ЗАЛЕ не пересекается. Как я понимаю, это триггер BEFORE INSERT и при добавлении новой записи проверяются все существующие записи, в которых номер зала равен добавляемому, и в них добавляемое время начала и конца занятия проверяются на пересечения с существующими записями. Но я не имею ни малейшего понятия, как написать такой триггер, нужна помощь.

Структура таблицы занятий:

```
CREATE TABLE lesson
( lesson_id number(5) NOT NULL,
lesson_section_id number(5) NOT NULL,
lesson_coach_id number(5) NOT NULL,
lesson_room number(5) NOT NULL,
lesson_start_date date NOT NULL,
lesson_end_date date NOT NULL,
lesson_cost number(5),
FOREIGN KEY (lesson_section_id) REFERENCES sections(section_id),
FOREIGN KEY (lesson_coach_id) REFERENCES coachs(coach_id),
CONSTRAINT lesson_pk PRIMARY KEY (lesson_id)
);
```

Нужно проверить чтобы в одинаковом зале (lesson_room) промежутки начала и конца занятий не пересекались (lesson_start_date и lesson_end_date в них хранится и дата и время начала и конца занятия соответственно)

Comment: Записи могут исправляться? Т.е. не только INSERT, но и UPDATE будет?

Comment: Да, могут обновляться. Но на данный момент триггера на INSERT будет достаточно, с его помощью на UPDATE я сделаю сам

Comment: Почему вы решили, что нужен триггер? Проверить необходимое условие до вставки вроде первое, что приходит на ум.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если решать проблему в лоб, то в триггере `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` (без `FOR ECH ROW`) необходимо подсчитать количество совпадений, если больше одного, то вывести ошибку.

```
create or replace trigger TRG_AIU_LESSON
  after insert or update on LESSON 
declare
  v_cnt integer;
begin
  select
    count(*) into v_cnt
  from lesson l1,
       lesson l2
  where l1.lesson_id <> l2.lesson_id
  and   l1.lesson_room = l2.lesson_room
  and   l1.lesson_start_date <= l2.lesson_end_date
  and   l2.lesson_start_date <= l1.lesson_end_date

 if v_cnt > 0 then
   raise_application_error(-20001, 'Пересечение');
 end if;
end TRG_AIU_LESSON;
```

Проблема в том, что при росте числа записей это будет замедлять внесение изменений.

Решение можно улучшить, используя [COMPOUND TRIGGER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020).

Comment: Если в таблице изначально есть хотя бя одна пара пересекающихся записей - этот код нафиг вообще заблокирует INSERT и UPDATE. Автор не просил чекать существующие данные - только вставляемые/исправляемые записи...

Comment: Я думаю, в реальной ситуации проверка начнется с какой-то даты. Эту дату можно без труда добавить в условие запроса.

Comment: А неважно... всё равно если старая ошибка блокирует ввод до тех пор, пока её не исправят или не отрубят этот триггер - это нехорошо. А если старые данные вообще нельзя исправлять? всё, работа встала навсегда?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Допустим, мы решили с мая придерживатся этого правила, тогда добавляем условие `l1.lesson_start_date >= to_date('01.05.2020') and l2.lesson_start_date >= to_date('01.05.2020')` проверка работает, старые данные не трогаем, их даже менять можно. Но если уже что-то успели ввести про май, то это предварительно все рано надо выровнять.

Comment: Этот триггер работает, спасибо. Попробую допилить с помощью COMPOUND TRIGGER.

Comment: А почему вы решили предложить триггер как решение, да ещё after?

Comment: Потому что автор писал, что хочет использовать триггер. И в триггере before такой проверки не сделать.

Comment: _Потому что автор писал, что хочет использовать триггер_, это все пишут, у кого ещё мало опыта. Можно было бы первым комментарием уточнить - нужен ли действительно.

Answer (score 2):

Триггер здесь не нужен. Проверять условие надо до вставки, а не во время её. Попробуйте:

```sql
create or replace procedure createLesson (room number, s date, e date) is
begin 
    for r in (
        select *
        from lesson
        where lesson_room = room
        and lesson_start_date < e and lesson_end_date > s) loop  
        raise_application_error (-20000, 'The room '||r.lesson_room||' already booked for '||
            r.lesson_id||'/'||r.lesson_start_date||' till '||r.lesson_end_date);
    end loop;
    insert into lesson values (null, room, s, e);
    dbms_output.put_line (sql%rowcount||' row inserted.');
end;
/
```

Сама вставка:

```sql
exec createLesson (1, date'2020-05-07'+10/24, date'2020-05-07'+12/24)

1 row inserted.

exec createLesson (1, date'2020-05-07'+11/24, date'2020-05-07'+13/24)

ORA-20000: The room 1 already booked for 1/2020-05-07 10:00:00 till 2020-05-07 12:00:00
```

Comment: `Триггер здесь не нужен` к чему такая категоричность? Ситуации бывают разные допустим у нас покупное ПО, а такую проверку хотим делать. В этом случае ваша процедура никак не поможет. И если уж на то пошло, то зачем цикл, чтобы не заводить переменную?

Comment: Почему категоричность? Ситуации действительно разные бывают, и если автору нужен действительно триггер, то вы уже  дали ответ. Но тему возможно найдут из поисковиков, и там ситуация будет возможно другая. Так почему не предложить ещё одно решение? В цикле да, сэкономил на переменной, всё равно на первой итерации исключение.